# Styling div hover action to not move other elements

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a list of 100 items on the screen and some descriptions are longer than the width of the div so I'm cutting the remaining part of it to keep them all in the same size. On the hover, I would like to display all the data. I managed to do it but now when I hover on one item all items underneath are moving downwards. I would like to move hovered div forward and keep all other tiles in the same place.

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/wojtekj89/pen/qgmWNB)

```html
<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/1a/69/cf/1a69cf82-2cfe-a7e1-a79c-cb9d7d67b710/886447513651.jpg/170x170bb-85.png"></div>
  <div class="album-card">
    <div class="name">Rent (Original Soundtrack of the Fox Live Television Event)</div>
    <div class="artist">Original Television Cast of Rent Live</div>
    <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/1a/69/cf/1a69cf82-2cfe-a7e1-a79c-cb9d7d67b710/886447513651.jpg/170x170bb-85.png"></div>
  <div class="album-card">
    <div class="name">Rent (Original Soundtrack of the Fox Live Television Event)</div>
    <div class="artist">Original Television Cast of Rent Live</div>
    <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.album-item {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 25px;
}

img {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.8, 0.4, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.8, 0.4, 1);
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

  &:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.album-card {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  &:hover {
    color: yellow;
    white-space: normal;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: 550;
  }

  .artist {
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  .date {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
```

I expect image description to display on top of the image underneath so it doesn't move the whole list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without duplicating the content: https://codepen.io/dmegatool/pen/jdmOgq

Is that the effect you're looking for ?

New css :

```
.album-item {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 25px;
  margin-bottom:75px;
}

img {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.8, 0.4, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.8, 0.4, 1);
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: 1px solid transparent;


  &:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.album-card {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:170px;
  background-color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;


  &:hover {
    color: yellow;
    white-space: normal;
    height: auto;
    z-index:10;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: 550;
  }

  .artist {
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  .date {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
```

Untouched HTML :

```
<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/1a/69/cf/1a69cf82-2cfe-a7e1-a79c-cb9d7d67b710/886447513651.jpg/170x170bb-85.png"></div>
  <div class="album-card">
    <div class="name">Rent (Original Soundtrack of the Fox Live Television Event)</div>
    <div class="artist">Original Television Cast of Rent Live</div>
    <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/1a/69/cf/1a69cf82-2cfe-a7e1-a79c-cb9d7d67b710/886447513651.jpg/170x170bb-85.png"></div>
  <div class="album-card">
    <div class="name">Rent (Original Soundtrack of the Fox Live Television Event)</div>
    <div class="artist">Original Television Cast of Rent Live</div>
    <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo+src](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJPgMV?editors=1100)

There is a workaround for this, which is to show a copy on top of the text element without the ellipsis when hovering.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div class="hover">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .hover{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.wrapper:hover .hover{
  display: block;
}
.text{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```